# Is "Literature" a pointless tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think [literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) is pointless, but I do think [literary-techniques](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-techniques) (total 19 questions) is a potentially useful tag.

I also think some of the [29 questions currently tagged literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) should be using *literary-techniques* (for others, the tag should just be removed).

So - is "Literature" a pointless tag? Vote this question up if you agree, down if you want to keep it.

Comment: Did you just see the tag-wiki edit too?

Comment: @simchona: Yes. I didn't endorse it (did you?) but it made me think - and when I found we already had *literary-techniques*, I just thought plain *literature* was either too vague, or would probably only suit questions that should be on writers.se anyway.

Comment: No, I didn't even vote on it because it seems to be a meta tag--it describes what's in the question, not the question itself

Comment: I don't see the big deal. It may be vague, or it may just be used vaguely. I don't think it's pointless (any more than any of the tags), because it can help someone find a question that has something to do with literature. But if you did all the work and removed it or gave a more accurate tag, I'd be OK with that.

Comment: @Mitch: Sure, it's no big deal. I'll happily clean up a few Q's if the votes here endorse getting rid of the tag. But I'm intrigued by the idea that you think there might be a "more accurate tag" (other than *iterary-techniques*). It seems to me that for most of the questions that use *literature*, it just means *"I found this expression in a book"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I agree that most uses of it are the vague 'has something to do with a book'. But I don't think that is unuseful. I don't think there'll be a more accurate term to replace 'literature'that still collects those 29 together. But I'm just open to the possibility that there is. Or maybe it's just the thought of bothering about it.

Comment: It seems possible that there could be language reserved to literature, including poetry, and not found much in spoken language. Not that I think that that tag implies that.

Answer (score 4):

[literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) should be considered along with [books](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books). The latter is described as follows:

> Questions about the English Language, with the cause for the question found in books read by the Original Poster.

IMO, [literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) should be merged with [books](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), with one marked as a synonym of the other, along with a broader purpose than "*something he read in a book*".

If [literary-techniques](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-techniques) is useful, then it should, first of all, carry a description that does not immediately make it a candidate for writers.se.